# C++ Recursive insert for a linked list

Tags: c++, recursion

When I'm implementing the recursive insert of a node into the linked list and display it, I don't get anything. I don't understand how to solve the problem.

My code is:

```
template <class H> class Node {
    private:
        H key;
        Node <H> *next;

    public:
        Node(H key) {
            this->key = key;
            next = NULL;
        }

        Node(H key, Node <H> * next) {
            this->key = key;
            this->next = next;
        }

        void setKey(H key) {
            this->key = key;
        }

        void setNext(Node <H> * next) {
            this->next = next;
        }

        H getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        Node <H> *getNext() {
            return next;
        }    
};

template <class H> class LinkedList {
    private:
        Node <H>  *header;

        Node <H> * insertHead( Node <H>*  header, H data)
        {
            if (header == NULL) 
                return new Node <H>(data);
            else
                header->setNext(insertHead(header->getNext(), data));

            return header;
        }

    public:    
        LinkedList() {
            header == NULL;
        }

        LinkedList <H> *insert(int x) {
            insertHead(header,x);
            return this;
        }

        void print() {
            Node <H> *tmp = header;

            while (tmp != NULL) {
                cout << tmp->getKey() << " ";
                tmp = tmp->getNext();
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList <int> *lset = new LinkedList <int> ();
    lset->insert(89)->insert(56)->insert(8);
    lset->print();    
}
```

In the main function I created a new Linked list and then invoked the insert function. I'm sure that there is the problem in the recursive insert therefore I can't identify it.

Comment: I don't see a recursive insert.

Comment: "Node <H> * insertHead "

Comment: Your problem is header is always null because you pass by value in `Node <H> * insertHead( Node <H>*  header, H data)`

Comment: ***therefore I can't identify it*** That is what a debugger is for. Single step through your code looking at your variables at each and you will see the issue. If you don't have a debugger I recommend using Visual Studio if you can. It has one of the best debugging environments.

Comment: If I pass by reference I get the following error: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Node*&' from an rvalue of type 'Node*'

Comment: I see. Put that back and change `insertHead(header,x);` to `header = insertHead(header,x);` https://ideone.com/g2D488

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not changing the root node `header` after adding the first node. `header` was still null after the addition of the node. The fix is to change

```
    LinkedList <H> *insert(int x) {
        insertHead(header,x);
        return this;
    }
```

to

```
    LinkedList <H> *insert(int x) {
        header = insertHead(header,x);
        return this;
    }
```

The returned node from insertHead() is the root node.